# Trying to set radio buttons programmatically using jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Why doesn't this work properly:

```
<input name="Fuel" type="radio" value="" title="Any" checked="checked">
<input name="Fuel" type="radio" value="1" title="Petrol">
<input name="Fuel" type="radio" value="2" title="Diesel">

<div class="options">Any</div>
<div class="options">Petrol</div>
<div class="options">Diesel</div>

$('.options').click(function(){
    $('input').removeAttr('checked');
    $('input[title="' + $(this).text() + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');   
});
```

See the working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4MTL2/

It works ok until you try to re-select a button that has already been selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [.prop( propertyName, value )](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value)

> *value* Type: String or Number or Boolean A value to set for the property.

```
$('.options').click(function () {
    $('input[title="' + $(this).text() + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/HZf6P/)</kbd>

Comment: Godlike. Thanks. I'll accept the answer as soon as Stackoverflow allows. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Read [`Attributes vs. Properties`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName) will help you understand more.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks for that link too. That starts to make a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is use .click()
Because it trigger click radio event as well, which is very important

The other solution that only change radio option property or attribute

will NOT trigger radio event !!!!!!!!

```
  $("#your_radio_option_ID_here").click()
```